# Unterschied zwischen "das Lesen" und "die Lesung"?

Tags: nominalization, semantics

[Aus vielen Verben können wir ganz einfach Nomen bilden](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/nominalisierung-verben-als-nomen/l-38464354/e-38468479), das heißt die Nominalisierung. Im Allgemeinen kann man auch ein Nomen [mit '-ung' bilden](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ung) oder '-keit', '-heit', '-nis', 'Ge-'. Dann, was ist der Unterschied zwischen der Bedeutungen? Zum Beispiel, "das Lesen" und "die Lesung".

Comment: These also exist in English: "Did you have a good read?" "The reading of the will". There are also "-er" (& "-erin" in German) forms. Most dictionaries list the meanings under the corresponding suffixes, but the straight nominalization has no suffix so that one requires some explanation.

Comment: @RDBury Please don't (ab-)use comments for giving half-baked answers. I see that you provide a lot of good content to the site, often in comments. But this is not what comments are meant to be for. (See https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)  Please elaborate your ideas into a full answer. Aligning with the infrastructure of this site will multiply the value of your contributions, which I find to be very good.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: I really didn't there there was an answer (half-baked or otherwise) in there. There's a comparison with English which doesn't imply anything about what happens in German, and I pointed out that much of the question can be answered by a dictionary lookup. I feel I'm in limbo here since I pretty good at looking up answers to my own questions, so I rarely post them, but there are people much more qualified to answer other people's questions than I am. I'll limit my comments in the future though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In der Regel beschreibt das substantivierte Verb eher einen *Vorgang*, das Ausführen der Tätigkeit, und die "Substantivierung durch Suffixderivation" mit *-ung* eher eine konkrete Seinseinheit, eine Entität, die in der Regel einen Ort in Raum und Zeit hat, mitunter auch das *Ergebnis* der ausgeführten Handlung.

Diese Regel wird regelmäßig auch bei der Übersetzung ins Englische deutlich: das substantivierte Verb kann in der Regel mit der Verlaufsform ins Englische übersetzt werden, für das Suffixderivat gibt es in der Regel ein eigenes englisches Wort.

Außerdem kann das substantivierte Verb in der Regel durch eine Konstruktion mit "Infinitiv mit zu" ersetzt werden, ohne dass sich der Sinn verändert. In der Regel ist die Konstruktion mit Infinitiv mit zu sogar stilistisch besser.

Hier einige Beispiele:

1. **Konkrete Entität:**

> Jetzt ist schnelles *Handeln* erforderlich. / Jetzt ist es erforderlich, schnell zu handeln. [Now it is necessary to act quickly.]
> *Die Handlung* des Films ist langweilig. [The plot of the movie is boring.]

> *Das Wohnen* in Berlin wird immer teurer. / In Berlin zu wohnen wird immer teurer. [Living in Berlin gets more and more expensive.]
> *Die Wohnung* ist gemütlich. [The apartment is cozy.]

2. **Ergebnis:**

> *Das Verbinden* der Bauteile wird mit Holzleim vorgenommen. [The parts are being connected with glue.]
> Es konnte keine *Verbindung* hergestellt werden. [It was impossible to establish a connection.]

Das gilt auch für das Verb *lesen*:

> Das *Lesen* fällt ihr leicht. / Es fällt ihr leicht, zu lesen. [Reading is easy for her.]
> Die *Lesung* ist beendet. [The lecture has ended.]

Auch hier beschreibt *das Lesen* die Tätigkeit zu lesen, während eine *Lesung* eine  Entität in Raum und Zeit ist.