# Unterschied zwischen 'Lesen' und 'lesen' als Nomen?

Tags: nominalization, semantics

Es scheint richtig zu sagen:

1. Es ist gut, den ganzen Tag zu lesen.
2. Den ganzen Tag **lesen** ist gut.
   Ich rate, dass 'Den ganzen Tag lesen' wirkt als ein Nomen hier. Aber die Nominalisierung von 'lesen' ist 'Lesen'. Dann, warum sagt man nicht so:
3. Das ganzen Tag **Lesen** ist gut.

Hier ist eine andere verwandte Frage: [Unterschied zwischen “das Lesen” und “die Lesung”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/62544/47366).

Answer (score 3):

Du hast recht. Der Satz muss tatsächlich

> Den ganzen Tag Lesen ist gut.

geschrieben werden, und zwar genau aus dem Grund, dass *Lesen* hier ein substantiviertes Verb ist. Wenn du das anders liest, dann liegt das daran, dass auch deutsche Muttersprachler*innen hin und wieder Fehler bei der Groß- und Kleinschreibung machen.

Comment: Ich bin hier ehrlich gesagt unsicher. Erweitert man den Satz, wäre die Großschreibung nicht richtig: „Den ganzen Tag *dieses Buch lesen* ist gut.“ Ich gebe allerdings zu, dass auch der Satz mich nicht zufiredenstellt, weil er mir wie ein Infinitiv mit vergessenem *zu* vorkommt. Ich würde schreiben: „Den ganzen Tag *(dieses Buch) zu lesen*, ist gut.“

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich denke, dass auch _Den ganzen Tag dieses Buch Lesen ist gut._ richtig wäre, und Kleinschreibung falsch wäre. Es ist eben gerade kein Infinitiv mit zu, sondern ein substantiviertes Verb. Ich denke, es ist verwirrend, weil der Infinitiv mit zu hier stilistisch viel natürlicher erscheint. Aber das ist ja nicht die Frage.

Comment: ich hab mal im Zweifelsfallsduden nachgesehen (*Infinitiv und Infinitivgruppe*, 4.): „Für die Groß- oder Kleinschreibung ist [...] entscheidend, ob die von dem Infinitiv abhängenden Wörter den Kasus beibehalten, den sie bei verbaler Konstruktion des Satzes hätten (*Er quält ein Tier ‒ Ein Tier quälen ist böse*), oder ob sie im Genitiv oder mit *von* angeschlossen werden (*[Das] Quälen eines Tieres / von Tieren ist böse*). Im ersten Falle ist der Infinitiv kleinzuschreiben [...]“ Ich fürchte, das gilt auch für unser Beispiel: *Er liest den ganzen Tag – Den ganzen Tag lesen*

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ah, OK. Danke für deine Recherche. Willst du eine Antwort draus machen? Immerhin hast du es rausgefunden, und meine Antwort ist dann nicht ganz richtig.

Comment: @jonathanscholbach, ich bin müde; heute nicht mehr. Sie könnten ja theoretisch eine zweite Antwort schreiben. Ich wäre dann auch nicht böse. ;-) Zumindest habe ich auch was dazugelernt, das reicht mir für heute.